# Understand if a GeoJsonLayer contains a given point

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps-android-api-2, geojson

I'm trying to understand if a given point (Latitude, Longitude) stays  inside a [GeoJsonLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/geojson). I've written this function but I don't have a bounding box for the layer so it's not working:

```kotlin
private fun isInsideLayer(userLatitude: Double, userLongitude: Double, layer: GeoJsonLayer): Boolean {
        val position = LatLng(userLatitude, userLongitude)
        return layer.boundingBox.contains(position)
    }
```

Below there's my JSON source.

```json
 {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              13.36761474609375,
              52.626602989514865
            ],
            [
              13.379974365234373,
              52.616181784632865
            ],
            [
              13.380317687988281,
              52.606175093642754
            ],
            [
              13.36761474609375,
              52.626602989514865
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
```

Anybody has a clue? Thanks

Comment: please add realistic sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is quite a theoretical question, unless knowing which kind of geometries are present - because a geometry is not necessarily a polygon, which could contain a point. else one could only check if a point matches exactly. the fundamental problem is that `.getBoundingBox()` returns a rectangle - and not a polygon, which does not permit proper matching due to the surrounding excess area.

eg. in order to construct a polygon there would be (at least) 3 geometries of type point required.

or (at least) 1 geometry of type polygon... which could be matched with [Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/)'s [PolyUtil](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html):

```
PolyUtil.containsLocation(position)
```

there are overall 10 different geometry objects for a feature object, which would need to be considered... is what [RFC 7946](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946) hints for.

Answer (score 1):

@Martin Zeitler, thank you for putting me on the right path.
My JSON source was actually containing a polygon (source added in the question). So, it was pretty easy to get the polygon from the feature by doing:

```java
private fun getPolygon(layer: GeoJsonLayer): GeoJsonPolygon? {
        for (feature in layer.features) {
            return feature.geometry as GeoJsonPolygon
        }
        return null
    }
```

After that, with PolyUtil is simple to determine if an arbitrary point is inside or outside the polygon by using:

```java
 private fun isInside(pointLatitude: Double, pointLongitude: Double, layer: GeoJsonLayer): Boolean {
        val polygon: GeoJsonPolygon? = getPolygon(layer)
        return PolyUtil.containsLocation(pointLatitude, pointLongitude, polygon!!.outerBoundaryCoordinates, false)
    }
```

Comment: in Kotlin, you could also check with `is GeoJsonPolygon`; hence there are 9 other geometries possible.